# How to reduce running time of code in python

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

The following code takes number of test cases as a first input value (a) and then (a) times, takes `2` values between `1≤x≤y≤10^9` as the second input value.

Output of the code is the number of values that are divisible by value that has defined in code, number of perfect squares and number of values that meet both criteria. Code works smoothly for small values but with large values running time is increasing. I need running time less than 5 seconds.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(input(), dtype=int)


B=[]
for i in range(a):
    b = np.array(input().split(), dtype=int)
    B.append(b)

       
def is_square(n):
    return (n**.5).is_integer()


for a, b in B:    
    print('{}'.format(sum(v % 12 == 0 for v in range(a, b+1))), '{}'.format(sum(is_square(v) for v in range(a, b+1))),'{}'.format(sum((v % 12 == 0) and is_square(v) for v in range(a, b+1))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use np.array, in that case it won't be any faster (or be even slower) than builtin types.
Some other ideas:

- Printing takes time so you can just append results to some list and print that out in the end instead.
- Saving results of conditions (divisible by 12 and perfect squares) to a separate lists and then creating a set from those two would make 3rd condition much quicker (thou you will increase significantly memory footprint)
- Testing like this is inefficient.
  For example 1st condition:
  "find number of items divisible by 12 in range (a,b)" - I would find first number in that range divisible by 12 (call it *x*), last number divisible by 12 (call it *y*), and then `(y-x)/12 + 1` should yield number of items; no need to check all of them.

2nd and 3rd condition, just generate a list of squares in that range:
Find smallest square in range (call it *x*), find largest square in range (call it *y*).
And then `sum( ((x**2)%12 == 0) for x in range(x,y+1) )`

Actually not much of programming here, more like math.
Let us know if you get it. Cheers.